# How to build a Facebook Presence application

Tags: facebook, api, token

There are some solutions that use RFID readers to do some actions on behalf of user (post, like). I read that it is so called "Facebook Presence", which was presented on the F8 conference in 2011.

There is a site you use to register a chip token (http://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=presence) but I can't find a word about it at Facebook Developers.

Do you know anything about this? Some API? How to build an application with this?

[An article on the topic.](http://tictechtips.blogspot.com/2011/10/facebook-presence-real-life-real-time.html)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.thetechlabs.com/tech-news/facebook-presence/:

> *“Facebook Presence” will not become one of the countless Facebook applications in the ever-growing site library. The project was simply showing off their cool new “places” feature which allows users the option to share their current location.*

Not sure if this still holds true – but since there is nothing about it anywhere in the docs, I’d say it most likely does.